# Getting a BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, system.addin

I have some addins from the System.AddIn. But when running the AddInStore.Rebuild,

```
string[] warnings = AddInStore.Rebuild(addInRoot);
```

then I get a warning string back:

> The file is not a valid binary:
>   D:\AK\AS\ConverterModule\output\AddIns\CompositeFileZip\7z.dll
>   File Name:
>   D:\AK\AS\ConverterModule\output\AddIns\Composi...

The 7z.dll is not the addin assembly, but the 7z file that the CompositeFileZip addin uses. I can't quite figure out what exactly the rebuild function is doing. Is it trying to add the 7z.dll as an addin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with System.AddIn or the 7z component, but a very common cause of `BadImageFormatException` is attempting to load an assembly that is marked as 64-bit (or dependent on a native 64-bit .dll) on a 32-bit system, or vice versa.

Check whether your `7z.dll` and its dependencies are built for the same architecture as the system where you see the `BadImageFormatException`.  You can do this from a Visual Studio command prompt by dumping the headers for `7z.dll` and looking for the machine architecture:

```
    C:\Program Files\7-Zip>dumpbin /headers 7z.dll | findstr /i machine
            8664 machine (x64)
```

Comment: ...or loading an assembly that is not a .Net assembly.

Comment: I do get the line you have. Then I switched to the 7z.dll that is build for 32-bit, but the BadImageFormatException is still there. The projects are build for "Any CPU".

Comment: Bummer.  If no other suggestions come in and it were me, I would enable .NET Framework source debugging, and set the debugger to break when an exception is raised.  Then you can see the details at the point where the BadImageFormatException is raised. See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) for details on enabling .NET FW source debugging. To break as soon as an Exception is raised, go to **Debug | Exceptions** in VS, then check the **Thrown** checkbox next to **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**.

Comment: The problem is that it is not thrown as an exception, so there is nothing to catch. Instead it is returned as a string[] that contains the warnings.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not raised and caught internally within the .NET Framework, then just returned to you as a string?  If this were the case, then the steps I mentioned above to break where the exception is raised internally in the .NET Framework would still be relevant.